# FileSystemWatcher on mapped network drive

Tags: c#, exception, filesystemwatcher, mapped-drive

Are there any special considerations (other than permissions) that you should take into account when implementing a FSW to monitor a mapped network drive.  Will the FSW throw an exception if the drive loses its connection?  If not (or if I just catch/handle that exception), will it be sufficient to poll the DirectoryInfo.Exists property to verfity the connection?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I have used the `FileSystemWatcher` to monitor a shared folder that exists on another computer in the network, and here is my experience:

1. You can check the connection via `File.Exists` or `Folder.Exists`.
2. The `FileSystemWatcher` will not throw an exception if the you lose connection to that shared folder.  Instead, whenever the connection is lost you will get this error message:
   "**The specified network name is no longer available**".  When you get that error, the `FSW` will no longer handle any data even if the connection is reestablished, so handle `FileSystemWatcher.Error` event and if the error is raised, reset `EnableRaisingEvents` to `true` again, or reinitialize the `FSW`

Comment: I ran across this same issue with a FSW I was using. But, at least with .NET 4, I found that all I needed to do after the share came back was to set `EnableRaisingEvents` to `false` (actually did this in the FSW_Error handler) and then when the share came back set `EnableRaisingEvents` to `true`. It started picking up events again.

Comment: Good to know, that is better than reinitialize :)